# Import IIS6 website configuration into IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, migration, metabase

I have many websites hosted on IIS6 and I want to migrate them to IIS7. It is enough if the basic configuration (folder, virtual folders inside, hostheaders, ) is migrated. a great part of the configuration is in web.config anyway. It is even okay if they're just created as "classic" mode applications.

I have tried the following things:

Msdeploy. This copies the whole directoried though, not good...
Tried exporting the iis websites to xml... Found nothing to give them to iis7...
Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer my own question:

You can use MSDeploy. But you have to add this argument: `-disableLink:Content`

This will prevent copying all the files.

For example now:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -disableLink:Content -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -dest:package=c:\Site1.zip > WebDeployPackage.log
```